# Man wakes from cryogenic sleep and discovers he doesn't know how to use a telephone

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have a memory from my childhood of seeing part of an American movie on TV wherein the male protagonist wakes from being cryogenically frozen to find himself in the 80's or  early 90's (which would have probably been about the time when the movie was filmed).  The man experiences a sequence of temporal culture shock events as he begins to try to interact with a world that's much different from the one he remembers before he was frozen.  In particular, he tries to use a pay-phone to call someone, but is confused at first because he's never seen a phone with a numeric keypad instead of a rotary dial, and soon thereafter completely stymied because all phone numbers consist of 7 digits or more, but all the phone numbers he remembers have fewer digits.

I believe this sequence of events occurs as exposition at the very beginning of the film.  Unfortunately I don't have any memory of the remainder of it.  I may not have ever seen the rest.

What is the name of the film?

Comment: May be [Forever Young](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104291/)

Comment: About what year did you see it?

Comment: @madmada based on the trailer on IMDB, I'm pretty sure that was it.  Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @dbugger It was probably sometime around 1996-1998, but I'm pretty sure madmada guessed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Forever Young](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104291/)

> A 1939 test pilot asks his best friend to use him as a guinea pig for a cryogenics experiment. Daniel McCormick wants to be frozen for a year so that he doesn't have to watch his love lying in a coma. The next thing Daniel knows is that he's been awoken in 1992.